# BA 185, what airplane configuration is this?

Tags: aircraft, seating, british-airways

On Monday, the 16th July 2018 I'll be flying BA185 from LHR to EWR on what is seemingly a 777.

[Seatguru](https://seatguru.com) claims that BA has four different 777s but none of those seem to match the layout that BA shows on seat selection. Does anyone know what's up here? (*edit*: one thing that strikes me as odd is that there seem to be only 20 rows of economy, shouldn't there be many more on a 777?)

- [777-200, four class](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/British_Airways/British_Airways_Boeing_777-200.php), shows rows 26 to 38 as economy
- [777-200, three class V1](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/British_Airways/British_Airways_Boeing_777-200B_2.php), shows rows 15 to 40 as economy
- [777-200, three class V2](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/British_Airways/British_Airways_Boeing_777-200ER.php), shows 15 to 40 as economy
- [777-300](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/British_Airways/British_Airways_Boeing_777_300.php), shows rows 26 to 50 as economy

However the seat selection diagram shows rows 21 to 35 as economy which really doesn't match any of the ones above.

[image: London to New York]

[image: rows 21 to 29]

[image: rows 30 to 35]

Comment: Seatguru might just be wrong or out of date.  There are lots of reports of inaccuracies in Seatguru's information.

Comment: isn't 15 rows of economy quite little for a transatlantic flight?

Comment: I don't know what answer you're expecting here. If BA could fill the entire aircraft with business class travellers they wouldn't fit any economy seats at all. They already do this with some  transatlantic flights from London City airport. As for the discrepancy, assume the airline that owns the plane knows how many seats are on board. SeatGuru has it wrong.

Comment: That said, BA has a "new" website and from my first attempt at using it, it seems to be pretty awful.  So I wouldn't be that surprised if the BA website has the wrong seating chart or is displaying it incorrectly.

Comment: Are they trying to fill those rows first so they have all the passengers conveniently grouped for service?

Comment: Does not appear to be the case here, but some flight companies show a seemingly incorrect seat map for the online seat selection tool, e.g. China Eastern, where some non-existent seats are displayed on the graphic tool but crossed over, such that they appear the same way as already selected, existing, seats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The definitive source for all things BA, including seat maps, is [the BA source](http://thebasource.com). The seat map you're looking at is from a [B777-200 17F/48J/24W/127Y](http://thebasource.com/seatmaps/772/17f48j24w127y.html) configuration.

Answer (score 1):

BA 185 is an Air Belgium operated flight, so the seat configuration isn't a standard BA one, as it isn't one of their planes.  AA also sell this route. I heard this might be BA experimenting with rostering and crew that undercuts their usual teams - as Air Belgium appears, indirectly, to be owned by BA's holding company (that also owns Iberia etc.)

Comment: Air Belgium only operates A340s.